# Laravel 5 - Clean objects in JSON array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this JSON incoming into a controller method:

```
$data = $request->get('data');
// output
// [{"key": "  Needs Trim  ", "value": "Two"}, {"key": "", "value": "empty key"}]
```

It's an array of objects and I need to to clean it before inserting it to the DB table:

- Trim leading/trailing spaces in key/value (first object)
- Remove any object with an empty key or value from array (second object)

So the final result after the cleaning of the array of objects would look like this:

```
[{"key": "Needs Trim", "value": "Two"}]
```

I looked into laravel's array helper functions but I can't seem to get the output I need after hours spent on this. It expects a different format, and their examples show nested arrays as opposed to objects...

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could just use array_map() with a custom handle function, right? Check the manual, plenty of examples thete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$data = json_decode('[{"key": "  Needs Trim  ", "value": "Two"}, {"key": "", "value": "empty key"}]');

foreach ( $data as $key => $el ) {
    foreach ( $el as $valKey => $val ) {
        if ( empty($val) ) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        } else {
            $el->$valKey = trim($val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, I'll just keep the question open a little longer to see if there is a solution that does not involve a nested foreach :)